# HMaster node disappeared while execute hbase shell command

Tags: hbase, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, ycsb

I am very new in HBase. I started to work with HBase very recently,In my Ubuntu server Standalone HBase work fine with Zookeeper. However, while I am trying to work with Pseudo-Distributed Local, it's having something strange that I don't understand. I have configured HBase *conf/hbase-site.xml* according to below:

```
<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
<value>true</value>
```

```
<name>hbase.rootdir</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
```

```
<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
<value>/home/username/zookeeper/new</value>
```

And I have setup HDFS for a Single Node Cluster of Pseudo-Distributed Operation. Most tricky part is when I run HBase,ZooKeeper and Hadoop(HDFS) and the "jps" command show the below information.

8998 HRegionServer

8066 ResourceManager

8229 NodeManager

7456 NameNode

7852 SecondaryNameNode

7045 QuorumPeerMain

9269 Jps

8815 HMaster

In addition after executing the "hbase shell" command it ask for the hbase operation.
hbase(main):001:0>

However, while I put "list" or create table command, its give

**ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null** .

And after exiting from hbase(main):001:0> I see

8998 HRegionServer

8066 ResourceManager

8229 NodeManager

7456 NameNode

9656 Jps

7852 SecondaryNameNode

7045 QuorumPeerMain

Here,
 **8815 HMaster** is disappeared.

I will greatly appreciate if someone help to find a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Search through your hbase-env.sh file for `HBASE_MANAGES_ZK` and make sure it is set to true:

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

Then head on over to your hbase-site.conf and let it know on which nodes to run Zookeeper (it will show up as some variation of QuorumPeer with jps):

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>localhost</value>
</property>
```

If that still doesn't work, try switching `localhost` in your conf files to your hostname (making sure it is in your machine's /etc/hosts file).

Comment: Thank you Feliks Montez for your valuable comment

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working fine with the below configuration file. The main problem was with the port number.

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2182</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>localhost:60010</value>
</property>
```

Comment: I had similar issue. I found out that I set hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort to 2181 in hbase-site.xml; however, zk was actually running at 2182. Then, I changed the value of hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort 2181 to 2182 in the hbase-site.xml, HMaster showed up after running jps. Last but not least, in hbase-evn.sh file, make sure that export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true.